# how to correlate two lists in python?

Tags: python, python-3.7

I have two lists with values stored in sub-lists.
I need to compare each element of each sub-list in list one with specific values and if the conditions are satisfied I need to extract the corresponding values from the sub-lists of second list.

I used the code below. However, I have problem when the code gives the values of second list. Actually, it prints all the first elements of all sub-lists in the list 2 instead of giving the first element of the sub-list related to the sub-list in the first list.

```
list1 = [[6.47, 1.34, 1.35],[5.41, 1.4, 1.39],[1.64, 2.43, 1.63]]
list2 = [[5820.0, 7870.0, 7600.0, 7590.0],[4660.0, 7770.0, 7480.0, 
7540.0],[4340.0, 9000.0, 5690.0, 50.0]]
for S in list1:
     if 2.43 <= (S[0]) or 1.01 > (S[0]):
      print(S[0])
      print('Single Axle')
      for W in list2:
           result = W[0]
           print(result)
```

My goal is to get results in this way:

```
6.47
single axle
5820
5.41
single axle
4660
```

But the answer I get is:

```
6.47
Single Axle
5820.0
4660.0
4340.0
5.41
Single Axle
5820.0
4660.0
4340.0
```

Comment: I mean, `for W in list2: print(W[0])` literally makes Python "print all the first elements of all sub-lists in the list 2", so I'm not sure what the problem is. You wrote this algorithm, Python executed it correctly, you got the corresponding results. If you want different output, you'll need a different algorithm

Comment: @ForceBru yes. exactly I get the result that I wrote, but I want another result, as I stated above. And I do not know how to tell python to get my desired results.

Comment: Do you want the first element of sublist in list2 that has the same index as the sublist you're looking at in list1, or do you just want the next sublist in list2 that you haven't printed yet?

Comment: @glibdud yes. for 6.47 I want the first element of only first sublist in list 2. similarly, for 5.41 I want only the first element of only second sublist in list2

Comment: Let me put it a different way... if the 2nd and 3rd sublists in list1 were reversed, would you want to print 4660.0 (because it's the first sublist you ahven't printed from yet) or 4340.0 (because it's the sublist that corresponds to the sublist in list1)?

Comment: Your logic implementation is totally absurd. What does `if 2.43 <= (S[0]) or 1.01 > (S[0])` even means. if sth is less than equal 2.43 or sth is less than 1.01?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this:

```
list1 = [[6.47, 1.34, 1.35],[5.41, 1.4, 1.39],[1.64, 2.43, 1.63]]
list2 = [[5820.0, 7870.0, 7600.0, 7590.0],[4660.0, 7770.0, 7480.0, 
7540.0],[4340.0, 9000.0, 5690.0, 50.0]]

for i, v in enumerate(list1):
     if 2.43 <= (v[0]) or 1.01 > (v[0]):
        print(v[0])
        print('Single Axle')
        print(list2[i][0])
```

The result is:

```
6.47
Single Axle
5820.0
5.41
Single Axle
4660.0
```

Comment: awsome! I tried to use enumerate function, but could not cause I am somehow new in python! anyway, appreciate your help!

Comment: I discovered it in this [amazing talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wf-BqAjZb8M&t=2s) from Raymond Hettinger

Comment: How about checking the all elements of first sublist instead of first elements of all sublist? I mean if I want to compare the values of 6.47, 1.34, 1.35 in the if condition, and then go to the elements of second sublist in list1. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @NargesTahaei I have shown how to check all the elements in list1 in the answer I provided

Comment: @mikeyj Thanks. your code solves my problem since it evaluates every item of sublists in list 1 one by one. However, I have another problem. The code should evaluate 3 other conditions as well. Actually I need to check 4 conditions for first element of sublist 1 to see which condition is satisfying the element.  Then I should check the 4 conditions for the second element of the sublist 1 and then.... . could you  please tell me where I should exactly put the 4 if else s  in the code? I tried but could not figure out!

Comment: @NargesTahaei I have updated my answer. Please put further comments regarding that answer on the answer itself

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is the:

```py
for W in list2:
    result = W[0]
    print(result)
```

This is iterating over `list2`, and printing the first item of *every* sublist.
Instead, you only want to select the corresponding sublist.

```py
list1 = [[6.47, 1.34, 1.35],[5.41, 1.4, 1.39],[1.64, 2.43, 1.63]]
list2 = [[5820.0, 7870.0, 7600.0, 7590.0],[4660.0, 7770.0, 7480.0, 
7540.0],[4340.0, 9000.0, 5690.0, 50.0]]
for Sindex, S in enumerate(list1):
    if 2.43 <= (S[0]) or 1.01 > (S[0]):
        print(S[0])
        print('Single Axle')
        print(list2[Sindex][0])
```

The `enumerate()` allows concise index retrieval, then that index is used to reference `list2`.

Answer (score 1):

For every sub_list in `list1` you are looping over all sub_lists in `list2`.
By using the [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) function you are iterating simultaneously over both lists and you can then directly extract the critical elements.

```
list1 = [
    [6.47, 1.34, 1.35],
    [5.41, 1.4, 1.39],
    [1.64, 2.43, 1.63],
    ]
list2 = [
    [5820.0, 7870.0, 7600.0, 7590.0],
    [4660.0, 7770.0, 7480.0, 7540.0],
    [4340.0, 9000.0, 5690.0, 50.0],
    ]

for list1_group, list2_group in zip(list1, list2):
    critical_element = list1_group[0]
    if critical_element < 1.01 or critical_element >= 2.43:
        print(critical_element)
        print('Single Axle')
        print(list2_group[0])
```

Gives output

```
6.47
Single Axle
5820.0
5.41
Single Axle
4660.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you want from the code that was posted. You've said that you want to check each element of the sublist, but your code will only look at the first element of each sublist.

This will get the indexes of each value in the sublists in `list1` which are less than `1.01` or greater than or equal to `2.43` and print them out with the corresponding values at the same indexes in `list2`:

```
list1 = [[6.47, 1.34, 1.35],[5.41, 1.4, 1.39],[1.64, 2.43, 1.63]]
list2 = [
   [5820.0, 7870.0, 7600.0, 7590.0],
   [4660.0, 7770.0, 7480.0, 7540.0],
   [4340.0, 9000.0, 5690.0, 50.0],
]

indexes = [
    (i, j)
    for i, sub_list in enumerate(list1)
    for j, num in enumerate(sub_list)
    if num < 1.01 or num >= 2.43
]

for i in indexes:
    print(list1[i[0]][i[1]])
    print('Single Axle')
    print(list2[i[0]][i[1]])
```

This will give you the following output:

```
6.47
Single Axle
5820.0
5.41
Single Axle
4660.0
2.43
Single Axle
9000.0
```

Although I think it would be neater to print the related data out on a single line:

```
for i in indexes:
    print(list1[i[0]][i[1]], 'Single Axle', list2[i[0]][i[1]])
```

Output:

```
6.47 Single Axle 5820.0
5.41 Single Axle 4660.0
2.43 Single Axle 9000.0
```

**EDIT**: From the latest comment, there are different conditions that need to be evaluated and produce different outputs? If this is the case, this might be easier using for loops.

```
for i, sub_list in enumerate(list1):
    for j, num in enumerate(sub_list):
        if num < 1.01 or num >= 2.43:
            print(num, 'Single Axle', list2[i][j])
        elif # some other condition:
            print(num, 'Different condition', list2[i][j])
```

You can use elif to keep adding new conditions if they are mutually exclusive. If the conditions overlap, use separate if statements instead

Comment: appreciate your great help. I was trying to put the elif s in your first code, but did not get result. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: As a final issue and one of my conditions, I try to sum two values, one by one, in list1 and compare with a specific value, the error I get is  TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable. The code that I try is:                                                                                                       if (num[j]+num[j+1]) < 3.65:
             print('Tridem Axle' , list2[i][j]+list2[i][j+1]+list2[i][j+2])      I see this error most of the time when coding on my project and it is really hard to deal with in different functions. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: So num is just a single number from the sublist. The outer for loop iterates over list1 to give sub_list and then the inner for loop iterates over the sub_list to give num. So num == list1[i][j] If you want to compare the total sums of the sub_list you can do if sum(sub_list) < 3.65: print('Tridem Axle', sum(list2[i])).  You can read up on the sum function here https://thepythonguru.com/python-builtin-functions/sum/

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Actually I do need to sum every two and three values of sublist and then compare with specific values and then do other calculations. And this is my final problem in the project! Hope I can find a way to deal with that. Appreciate your great help!